# How to access object variables in a polymorphed class Java

Tags: java, object

So as part of a project I have to use an array of type Vehicle which is abstracted to 2 subclasses motorized and pedal which then there are 4 subclasses that are polymorphed.

My question how I can access the variables in the object array of vehicle which is of the Vehicle type. Below is part current code that shows the setup.

```
//Main
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class DatabaseMain
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    String inputString;
    File inFile =  new File(args[0]);
    Scanner lineCounter = new Scanner(inFile);
    Scanner fileScan = new Scanner(inFile);

    File outFile = new File(args[1]);
    PrintStream printer = new PrintStream(outFile);

    int lineCount = 0;
    while (lineCounter.hasNextLine())
    {
        lineCount++;
        String linePoint = lineCounter.nextLine();
    }
    Vehicle[] vehicle =  new Vehicle[lineCount];
    inputString = fileScan.nextLine();

    String completeInputString = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < lineCount; i++)
    {   
     String inputFront = inputString.substring(0,2);
        if(inputFront.contains("b%"))
        {
            vehicle[i] = new Bicycle();
            vehicle[i].setup(inputString);
        }
     completeInputString = completeInputString + "\n" + inputString;

     if(fileScan.hasNextLine()) //Special Last run to handle end of File lines
     {
        inputString = fileScan.nextLine();
     }
    }
    printer.print(completeInputString);

}
}//CourseMain


//Bicycle.java
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Bicycle extends Pedal
{
String type;
String make;
int size;
int vehicleID;
int numberOfGears;
String owner;
int numberOfRiders;
public void setup(String inputString) 
{
    String[] parts = inputString.split("%");
    type = parts[0];
    make = parts[1];
    size = Integer.parseInt(parts[2]);
    vehicleID = Integer.parseInt(parts[3]);
    numberOfGears = Integer.parseInt(parts[4]);
    owner = parts[5];
    numberOfRiders = Integer.parseInt(parts[6]);
}
public String getMake() {return make;}

}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQwmb.png

Here is an image showing how the data is stored in the array of objects.

Note: I am not allowed to use ArrayList in this project

Comment: Perhaps I do not understand your question however it looks to me that you are accessing the array elements of the array `vehicle` with lines like `vehicle[i] = new Bicycle();` which is assigning a new `Bicycle` object into the i'th element of the array `vehicle`.

Comment: @scottb It would seem to be so however the way this project was described was that Bicycle and it's sister subclass Tricycle (not shown) inherit the empty constructor (setup()) from Pedal and Override using their own methods. Which was the process taught by my Professor.(Which in my opinion seems unnecessary considering you could just use the 4 subclasses and cut out the middle classes)

Comment: @RichardChambers: Yes that would be correct. To pose my question more easily is that the data is there in the array vehicle but I am unsure of how to access it so I can sort the information.

Comment: Could you improve the actual question and problem statement to better explain what you want to accomplish? Since your data is in an array and you have demonstrated that you know how to access the elements of an array, I am at a loss as to what else you are needing.

Answer (score 0):

Your first job should be to think about your problem, define a problem domain and then design an object model domain from it.

You have said that your decomposition involves a Vehicle type, that has two distict subtypes: PedalDrivenVehicle and MotorizedVehicle.  Note: Pedal is an exceedingly bad name for a subtype here.  From the type names, it is clear to anyone who reads the code that a PedalDrivenVehicle **is** a Vehicle.

So your code should look something like this so far:

```
public interface Vehicle { ... }

public abstract class PedalDrivenVehicle extends Vehicle { ... }

public abstract class MotorizedVehicle extends Vehicle { ... }
```

Whether Vehicle should be an interface or an abstract class is an important decision.  Interfaces should be used in Java whenever possible to define types, so the natural answer is that Vehicle should be an interface, however if there are implementation details in Vehicle common to all subtypes then it wouldn't be wrong to use an abstract class.

As I understand it, your question is how to access attributes of your Vehicles in an array of vehicles.  This is accomplished through your API which you should design before coding any of your classes.  For example, say Vehicle was an interface:

```
public interface Vehicle {
    setSize(int size);
    int getSize();
    setID(int ID);
    int getID();
    :
    :
}
```

The classes that implement your interface (eg. PedalDrivenVehicle and MotorizedVehicle) must now implement all these interface methods that clients of the API (which you designed) can use to access the attributes of all your Vehicle subtypes.

Comment: okay that could work the issue I foresee with this is that the other subclasses use slightly different lists of variables for the vehicles, so would I just define all the different vehicle variables and then only assign and grab the variables that I would need to use?

Comment: Joshua Bloch has said that *"you should spend as much time designing your API as you should writing the code for your classes."*  It's true that some of your attributes will be specific to only certain subtypes (or groups of subtypes).  You have a choice: you can include methods to work with those attributes in your API and have your contract specify that those methods are optional ... or ... you can code subtype specific methods.  The latter is easier, but requires that you use casts in your code.  If your hierarchy is well designed, you shouldn't have much of this.